# Prove or disprove ''If $\int_{c}^{d}f(x) dx=0,~\forall~ a\leq c <d \leq b$, then $f=0$ a.e''

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Q. Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function: Then prove or disprove

''If $\int_{c}^{d}f(x) dx=0,~\forall~ a\leq c <d \leq b$, then $f=0$ a.e''

I am sure about non-negative measurable functions by analysing the measure of the set $$A_n=\{x \in \Bbb R~:~f(x)\geq 1/n\},$$ since $$\{x \in \Bbb R~:~f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$
But, here the assumption is a bit different, $$\int_x^y fdm=0,~\text{for all}~a \leq x<y \leq b.$$ How to deal with? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably, $f$ is integrable. Use a monotone class argument: $\int_{(c,d]}f=0$ for all $(c,d]\subset [a,b]$. The collection of sets $\mathcal{C}:=\{(c,d]: a\leq c<d\leq b\}$ is a $\pi$-system. The class $\mathcal{D}$ of all measurable sets $D$ such that $\int_Df=0$ is a $\lambda$-system. Therefore $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: If it is integrable then $\phi(t) = \int_a^t f = 0$ is differentiable and $\phi'=0$, so $f = 0 $ ae.

Comment: You can take $d=c+\epsilon$ & hence it will vanish at every $c$

Comment: @copper.hat continuity of $f$ is not required here?

Comment: Any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable (or finite) union of disjoint open intervals, so the integral is $0$ over any open set. The regularity of $dm$ should imply that the integral is $0$ over any measurable set. Now just consider the sets $\{x: f(x)>0\}$ and $\{x: f(x)<0\}$.

Comment: @MessiLio no, just integrability.